# Mongo. How to count number of related documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I use nodejs and mongo DB. I have two collections.

---

```
var AveSchema = new Schema({
name: {
    type: String
},    
lot: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'LotModel'
}
});

var LotModelSchema = new Schema({
lot_name: {
    type: String
},
lot_description: {
    type: String
}});
```

---

I want to get all Lot's with number of Ave's in each Lot. Is an any way to do it with one request? I make an aggregation like this:

```
Ave.aggregate(
    { $group:
        { _id: '$lot', total: { $sum: 1 } }
    },
    function (err, avesinlot) { console.log(avesinlot); });
```

But then I need to iterate between all lots and assign num aves to them. Its much time on big collection. I think present a better way. Is anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: This is not very clear in explaining what you are trying to do. It sounds like you would be better off storing an an array of "Ave" objects in your "Lot" model and just getting the count of that. Better still just maintain a field that keeps the count as that will be a faster result than aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Neil, but here is litle litle part of real code, in real app the Ave is much more bigger and its very much aves for each lot (>10000). So, I think, separate aves to own collection is good idea.

Comment: Now I have more then 1 million aves, and have 1000 lots. Each Ave relate to one Lot. I want to get all lots and see how much aves depend to each lot.